# What is the current state of Swappable Consensus and Re-Genesis

Tags: consensus, cumulus, documentation

I've found these two open issues:

- [Re-Genesis #7458](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/7458)
- [Swappable Consensus #1304](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/1304)

and would be interested if there is more practical guidance on an example basis?

Answer (score 1):

Swappable consensus was a potential solution to the lifecycle of parachains when they lose their parachain slot, allowing them to swap their consensus to some solo-chain system, and then back to a parachain if they won another auction.

However, given the introduction of parathreads as a much better solution to this problem, I believe swappable consensus is not a feature being worked on anymore. Obviously the expert in this case is [@rob](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/users/283/rob).

I am not sure about the specific state or thinking around re-genesis. Best to keep [multiple questions to multiple posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

However, it seems at a high level, the process of re-genesis can be done with tools like [`fork-off-substrate`](https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate). Beyond that, halting one chain and starting another seems like a coordination issue that is solved off-chain or with some custom client logic.